# Why am I getting a compile error when I return a pointer to a Protocol?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
@protocol Runnable

- (id<Runnable>) works; //this compiles fine

- (Runnable *) broke; // get a compile error saying Expected ')' before 'Runnable'

@end
```

I'm not sure I understand why xCode complains about the `- (Runnable *) broke;` line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Protocols in Obj-C don't look syntactically like, say, "interfaces" in Java, where the syntax for interface pointers and subclass pointers are essentially the same.

The `id<Runnable>` is the idiomatic way that you say "an object that conforms to `Runnable`. An `id` is a reference to *any* type of object, and the `<` `>` notation expresses an explicit conformance to a given protocol for the purposes of type checking.

If you say `Foo *`, you're referring to an object of either type `Foo` or one of its subclasses.

This just happens to be the Obj-C syntax for this. With this syntax, the semantics are similar to what you'd get in, e.g. Java.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that the syntax is different. They function pretty much the same, it's just that Objective-C doesn't talk about objects that conform to a protocol as instances of that protocol.

Comment: @Chuck. Good clarification. Answer tweaked.